# How to sync all files of an Android Project version 3.3 on Github?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm having an issue when I try to add a project from Android Studio 3.3 on Github. The synchronization works fine but instead of uploading the entire project only the `app` folder is added. With earlier versions of Android Studio, all the files were added (including the gradle files and so on). What I do, right click on `app` project in the left tree, then Git, then repository and then Push...

How to upload all files of a project on Github? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1 .Select project Structure -> 2. Select(click) top project folder ->  3. `Vcs`- `Git` - `add` 4.Commit

Do a commit and push as regular .

Or in Git bash use command

```
git add --all
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add project on Github as public repository then you have one option "Share Project on GitHub" (VCS -> Import into version control -> Share Project on GitHub).

Comment: The same thing happens, only the app folder is added.

Comment: then try from bottom panel option "Version Control". if you have all files on "Unversioned Files" then right click on "Unversioned Files" and click on "Add to VCS". now you have all your files under "Default" right click on it and commit all files then push commit on your git.